# string comparison failing in python?

Tags: python

I have a small script which goes like this:

(Notice the comparison)

```
def readVariations(path_to_source_config):
varsTuple = []
source_file = open(path_to_source_config, "r")

for line in source_file:
    line_no_spaces = line.replace(" ","")
    if line_no_spaces[0] == '[':
        current_line_ = line_no_spaces.replace("[", "") 
        current_line = current_line_.replace("]", "")
        section = "ExecutionOptimizer"
        if current_line == section:
            print current_line
    #_tuple = section_name, option_name, range_start, range_end, step
    #varsTuple.append(_tuple)
return varsTuple
```

What it does is reads a config file (.cfg) and needs to check if it finds a particular string.

The following line comes up in the config file:

```
[ExecutionOptimizer]
```

For some reason the comparison is failing when the same string is encountered in the file.
Can you please tell me why.

Comment: why you dont use regular expressions ?

Comment: why don't you simply use `if '[ExecutionOptimizer]' == current_line.strip():`?

Comment: Yeah, I must start using those.

Comment: @Wildling Why implement it yourself? There is a `ConfigParser` in the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect `line` ends with a newline character, and it remains there throughout all of your `replace` operations. Then your comparison fails because "ExecutionOptimizer\n" doesn't equal "ExecutionOptimizer". You can discard the newline using `strip`:

```
line_no_spaces = line.strip().replace(" ","")
```

Answer (score -2):

Use "is" key word.
"==" is for equality testing

From a Python interpreter:

```
> a = 'tea'
> b = ''.join(['t', 'e', 'a'])
> a == b
True
> a is b
False
```

Comment: I dont understand. I am not trying to compare objects